# Test if user selects one or more checkboxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 3.2 app, I want to validate in a model that the user selects one or more checkboxes.  I don't want them all false.

This is my attempt:

```
if !(source_contractor? ^ source_other? ^ source_sqft_cost? ^ source_rs_means? ^ source_facilities_management?)
  errors.add(:base, "Specify Estimate Source")
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `unless` and `or`:

```
unless source_contractor or
       source_other or
       source_sqft_cost or
       source_rs_means or
       source_facilities_management
```

This branch will be triggered only if all checkboxes were `false`.